# Adobe Premiere clip duration lag

Tags: premiere, adobe

Sort of a strange issue with Premiere. As you are aware you can change a clips duration by sliding the clip from the end back or fourth. For some reason, in a particular project this takes at least 3 seconds to move in or out (almost like lag). I've confirmed that in other projects this doesn't happen, so it wasn't something I changed in the settings. Have any of you ever experienced this or have any suggestions?

I already did a lot of work in the project, and I would hate to do that over again.

Comment: Does this happen with all clips in this project? Do these clips, when used in another project, still show the same behaviour?

Comment: When you say "move in and out" do you mean playing through the clip or dragging the playhead.. What wrapper/codec (format) are your clips?  How many layers of video do you have overlapping? Any effects or transitions on the clip? How much RAM on your computer? What speed is your cpu?

Comment: It was an issue emic to this project, trial-and-error, I was able to figure it out. Computer specs wouldn't factor into it as I've said, it was fine before in similar situations.

Comment: Computer specs could well be a factor. It sounds like a real-time memory or cpu use issue with the plugin. More information in the question would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: issue was audio effect on the master that was causing the clip duration change lag. iZotope RX was the plugin causing this if anyone is interested!

Answer (score 0):

This smells of disk I/O problems.

When you resize a clip in the timeline as you described, two things are happening:
1) The project data and clip metadata are modified
2) The video file itself is reloaded to refresh any thumbnails, etc.

Thus, two things I would try to troubleshoot your situation:
For problems with (1), I would save/export another copy of the project file.  See if openings this copy shows any improvement.
For problems with (2), make a copy of the source clip on disk, import that copy into the project and try using the new file instead.

I don't have access to Adobe Premiere source code, so I can't tell for certain what the issue is, but the above is what I would try in an attempt to troubleshoot.

Let me know how it goes.  Good luck!